# VirtualBox (5) - Make guest see VDI as USB stick?

Tags: windows-7, usb, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am using VirtualBox 5 on Windows 7 as my virtual machine program of choice. I am running a linux program on it, but it requires to save on USB stick (program written by my friend, who i lost contact with). Now i dont own any real usb sticks but i want to use this program.

**End of explaination. Time for actual question**

My question is: Is it possible to make VirtualBox guest see **VDI** file as **USB Stick?** I have **Virtual Box Extension Pack** installed.

EDIT: To be more clear, the "program" is basically a live distro! You can still access terminal in it and it is based on Debian.

Comment: Do you know how the program determines a block device is a USB drive?

Comment: i think it has something to do with direct kernel requests